# Висячий дефис с общей первой частью

Tags: пунктуация

Есть два слова: ПСИ-ранец и ПСИ-карамель (из игры). Хотим объединить, но возник спор: "-карамель" или "карамель"? Может ли висячий дефис быть перед словом. Все справочные ресурсы покрывают только случаи с общей второй частью (теле- и радиокоммуникация), а как быть при первой общей части?

Comment: А что такое "Пси ранец" и "Пси карамель"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Самокат и -вар* ПМСМ не понятно, что это *Самокат и Самовар*
Правила написаны для сложных русских слов. А у Вас конструкция не имеющая названия в русском языке.

"... как быть при первой общей части?"
Использовать стандартное решение - написать совсем по другому. В Вашем случае уйти от необходимости использовать "*висячий дефис перед словом*" Например:

Из козлонога выпадает ПСИ-лут: ранец и карамель.
У торговца можно купить даже ПСИ-вещи:ранец и карамель.